# How I resize an object in ARCore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I show the 3D object in ArFragment. So I put .obj file and .mtl file at sampledata folder. And I right click on obj file, and select Import Sceneform Asset to add .sfa / .sfb file.

So I can show the 3d object when I mark the image, but the object is too big.

This is my .sfa file detail

```
{
   bound_relative_root: {
      x: 0.5,
      y: 0,
      z: 0.5,
   },
   materials: [
      {
         name: "Material.001",
         parameters: [
            {
               baseColor: null,
            },
            {
               baseColorTint: [
                  0.80000000000000004,
                  0.80000000000000004,
                  0.80000000000000004,
                  1,
               ],
            },
            {
               metallic: 1,
            },
            {
               roughness: 0.120695,
            },
            {
               opacity: null,
            },
         ],
         source: "build/sceneform_sdk/default_materials/obj_material.sfm",
      },
   ],
   model: {
      attributes: [
         "Position",
         "TexCoord",
         "Orientation",
      ],
      collision: {},
      file: "sampledata/dongbaek.obj",
      name: "dongbaek",
      recenter: "root",
      scale: 0.200000
   },
   version: "0.52:1",
}
```

I think it can resize by scale part, but I change the value, it dosen't change. same size

So How I can resize 3d object?

Is there any problem at add 3d object file to make .sfa / .sfb file?(Import Sceneform Asset)

If you know about it, please help me.

Comment: You can use `ScaleController` to resize the object in scenform arcore

Answer (score 14):

Object scaling is changed by the Scale Controller. By setting minScale and maxScale value. Before setting parent - anchor node. See example below.

```
      // Create the Anchor.
      Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
      AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
      anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

      // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
      TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
// Maxscale must be greater than minscale
        node.getScaleController().setMaxScale(0.02f);
        node.getScaleController().setMinScale(0.01f);

        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        node.setRenderable(renderable);
        node.select();
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, although I will add that the MaxScale must be greater than the MinScale, because then you get an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Different approaches depending on your project:

1. Change the scale value, regenerate your sfb files
2. Put your node into a [TransformableNode](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode) and let [ScaleController](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/ScaleController) scale your model
3. Directly use [setLocalScale](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/Node#setLocalScale(com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Vector3)) or setWorldScale
4. Scale your .obj file, and then generate the .sfa and .sfb files

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to resize your model in ARCore:

```java
TransformationSystem transSys;
transSys = MainActivity.getArFragment().getTransformationSystem();
TransformableNode myNode = new TransformableNode(transSys);

myNode.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f));
myNode.setParent(anchorNode);
//myNode.setParent(sceneView.getScene());
myNode.setRenderable(myModelRenderable);

sceneView.getScene().addChild(node);
myNode.select();
```